# Findall call not working when certain def has been called

Tags: python

So, this is my 3. post about the subject, sorry for that but i have become the more and less clever:

SO, the full code:
i have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<list>
    <a>
        <item name="Apple" kcal="36" />
        <item name="Apricot" kcal="78" />
    </a>
    <b>
        <item name="Banana" kcal="53" />
        <item name="Bnoodles" kcal="87" />
    </b>
</list>
```

and my python code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("Alphabet.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

font1 = "Arial, 24"
counterRow = 1
counterColumn = 0


def test():
    print("PRINTOUT")
    for items in root.findall("a/item"):
        print(items.get("name"))


def setup():

    for letters in root:
        global counterRow
        global counterColumn
        letters.tag = Button(vindue, text=letters.tag, font=font1, command=test)\
            .grid(row=counterRow, column=counterColumn, sticky="nsew")
        counterColumn += 1
        if counterColumn > 7:
            counterRow += 1
            counterColumn = 0


vindue = Tk()
# setup()
button1 = Button(vindue, text="test", command=setup).grid(row=5)
button2 = Button(vindue, text="test", command=test).grid(row=6)
vindue.mainloop()
```

Right so the scenario plays out like this:
when i run the script and i press button2 first, i get a print out like this:

```
PRINTOUT
Apple
Apricot
```

if i press Button1 and get the "A" and "B" button and then press either of them i only get:

```
PRINTOUT
```

if i press Button1 and get the "A" and "B" button - but THEN press Button2 then i get:

```
PRINTOUT
```

I don't understand what goes wrong?

Edit: The solution:
So you cannot use letters.tag directly, but if you assign that to a holder of some sort, it works just fine

```
def setup():

    for letters in root:
        global counterRow
        global counterColumn
        str = letters.tag
        str = Button(vindue, text=letters.tag, font=font1, command=test)\
            .grid(row=counterRow, column=counterColumn, sticky="nsew")
        counterColumn += 1
        if counterColumn > 7:
            counterRow += 1
            counterColumn = 0
```

Comment: Why does it sound like your first sentence was not written by the same person who wrote the rest of the question...

Comment: @musefan i erhm, dunno?

Comment: You assign to `letters.tag` in the loop, so I think that is going to change all the `a` elements into something different. Not sure what it does though as I don't know what the `.grid()` method of a Tk Button returns.

Comment: @Duncan sure, a will be set to a = Button(..) same for b = Button(..), but that should not change the root.findall? i am not using a and b for anything as buttons, the xml is not being changed

Comment: On the contrary, chnging the xml is exactly what you are doing. Assigning to the `tag` attribute of an xml element changes the element's tag. I've added this as an answer.

Comment: @Duncan +1, you i right (i guess, i have no idea) but it seems when i did not assign letters.tag directly it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop you change the tag of each top level element. You appear to be assigning a Tk `Button` as the tag, but in fact any change to the tag will show a similar result.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse("Alphabet.xml")
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> list(root.findall("a/item"))
[<Element 'item' at 0x7fbbd755e1d0>, <Element 'item' at 0x7fbbd755e290>]
>>> for letters in root:
...   print letters
...
<Element 'a' at 0x7fbbd755e190>
<Element 'b' at 0x7fbbd755e350>
>>> for letters in root:
...   letters.tag = 'foo'
...
>>> for letters in root:
...   print letters
...
<Element 'foo' at 0x7fbbd755e190>
<Element 'foo' at 0x7fbbd755e350>
>>> list(root.findall("a/item"))
[]
>>>
```

I don't know what you expect to do assigning to the `tag` of each XML element in `root`, but that's why you dn't have any `a` tags after you run `setup()`

Comment: I made an update as an edit. I clearly reached a glass ceiling in my programming knowledge. Thank you for your help.